# Найти наибольший простой делитель одного целого числа БЕЗ ДЕЛЕНИЯ

Tags: c, алгоритм, математика, теория-чисел

Нужен простой наибольший делитель целого числа

!НО по заданию **нельзя** использовать операции деления ( `/` и `%` )

Нужен алгоритм. не пойму от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: Генерируй простые числа решетом. Используй сложение и вычитание. А потом проверяй на делимость точно так же сложением и вычитанием. Ну и используй ускоренные методы проверки на делимость для малых простых.

Comment: Реализуйте свои операции деления и остатка от деления без использования библиотечных, и потом используйте их в стандартном алгоритме.

Comment: ничего не понял. каким решетом? какие ускоренные методы?

Comment: А диапазон значений этого самого целого числа?

Comment: @Akina, про решето согласен, а вот проверка делимости тут лишняя.

Comment: @Qwertiy Проще проверить чётность последней цифры, чем вычитаниями выяснять, чётно число или не очень.

Comment: @Akina, вообще не понял, кому и зачем нужна последняя цифра. Ну и вычитаний в моём коде тоже нет.

Comment: @Akina, кстати, в как получить последнюю цифру не используя деление?

Comment: @Qwertiy Преобразование в строку не является ни делением, ни умножением.

Comment: @Akina, типа вызов стандартной функции, которая внутри использует деление не считается использованием деления? Больше на читинг похоже)))

Comment: @Akina, как без деления вы узнаете последнюю цифру? Положитесь на двоичное представление?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну, кстати, битовые операции, вроде, не запрещены.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да вообще ничего, кроме деления и умножения не запрещено... например, извлечение квадратного корня.

Comment: Здесь идёт перебор чисел от 2 до n-1. Каждое число вычитается  из  n до тех пор пока не будет равно нулю. Если по итогу ноль. Оно подходит и мы его проверяем повторно как само число n.

Answer (score 3):

Ну... неэффективно, конечно, но...

```
int MaxFactor(int N)
{
    if (N < 2) return -1;  // некорректное значение
    vector<int> v(N+1,0);
    for(int k = 2; k <= N; ++k)
    {
        if (v[k]) continue;
        for(int m = k*2; m <= N; m += k)
            v[m] = k;
    }
    return v[N] ? v[N] : N;
}
```

Ой, не глянул, что С... Тогда

```
int MaxFactor(int N)
{
    if (N < 2) return -1;  // некорректное значение
    int * v = calloc(N+1,sizeof(int));
    for(int k = 2; k <= N; ++k)
    {
        if (v[k]) continue;
        for(int m = k*2; m <= N; m += k)
            v[m] = k;
    }
    N = v[N] ? v[N] : N;
    free(v);
    return N;
}
```

Comment: Ой.. У тебя почти тот же алгоритм, что и у меня...

Comment: А в чём неэффективность? Ваш алгоритм на один децл медленнее линейного.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, неэффективность в том, что ради одного числа мы жрём кучу памяти (причём с выделением и освобождением) и делаем довольно затратные вычисления, когда просто цикл с делением отработал бы куда быстрее. А вот если бы надо было посчитать для многих чисел, то такой алгоритм с однократным расчётом таблицы и мгновенными ответами был бы эффективнее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А не ближе к O(N^2)? Что-то не могу сообразить, внешний цикл - O(N), но для каждого простого еще один цикл... O(N^2) не дотягивает, но O(N lg N) перекрывает, нет? Ну и по памяти — O(N).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, кстати, асимптотика тут O(n*lb(n)), а не линейная.

Comment: Асимптотика меньше O(nlb(n)) из-за `continue` под `if`. Кажется должно быть O(nlog(log(n))). А log(log(n)) это и есть децл.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Формально `continue` тоже учитывается :)

Comment: @Harry, пусть нет `continue`. Тогда для каждого `k` делаем `N/k` итераций. Сумма по `k` даст `N(1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/k + ... + 1/N`). В скобках расписан `logN` (частичная сумма гармонического ряда). То есть получаем `NlogN` без `continue`. Дальше нестрого:  цикл вызывается не для всех `k`, только для простых. А их примерно `N/logN`. Если прочитать умную статью, то можно найти `Nlog(log(N))` для этого варианта.

Comment: В том-то и прелесть решета, что оно оказывается неожиданно эффективно по времени. Константа так мала, что это лучший способ для небольших чисел. Почти линейный. Вот память - это проблема. Но тут на сцене появляется сегментированное решето.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy OK, уговорили. Всегда легко уговорить, что ты написал быструю программу :)

Answer (score 2):

Не надо недооценивать решето эратосфена: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##ZY/RSsMwFIbvz1P8bgzatZNEdAppBB9Ar4XZC2nSLaCZ7RoSGHv2mjgnTi8P@b585zSLddOM49TY5s0pjWo3KLO93NwTTZVujdV4fHh@AmfXdze3SyJnd2ZttYJapYcaEntWgh8EkbED3l@NzXLaE9Bue2Q/fJBXAqFKkkBRhDwSgGmRXahVqI/jX6mTQaD7lrpChhOG2O9SPMTuf4v/suaSM3b0zjEvmYCv@DLt408/f/TxjDabzBwWmLkXOylj2ZcpWPg6/@r1enC9BRN0GMdP)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXN 1048576

unsigned d[MAXN] = {0, 1};

int main()
{
  for (unsigned x=2; x<MAXN; ++x)
    if (!d[x])
      for (unsigned q=x; q<MAXN; q+=x)
        d[q] = x;

  for (unsigned q=1; q<MAXN; q*=100)
    for (unsigned w=0; w<16; ++w)
      printf("%u - %u\n", q+w, d[q+w]);

  return 0;
}
```

```
1 - 1
2 - 2
3 - 3
4 - 2
5 - 5
6 - 3
7 - 7
8 - 2
9 - 3
10 - 5
11 - 11
12 - 3
13 - 13
14 - 7
15 - 5
16 - 2
100 - 5
101 - 101
102 - 17
103 - 103
104 - 13
105 - 7
106 - 53
107 - 107
108 - 3
109 - 109
110 - 11
111 - 37
112 - 7
113 - 113
114 - 19
115 - 23
10000 - 5
10001 - 137
10002 - 1667
10003 - 1429
10004 - 61
10005 - 29
10006 - 5003
10007 - 10007
10008 - 139
10009 - 10009
10010 - 13
10011 - 71
10012 - 2503
10013 - 31
10014 - 1669
10015 - 2003
1000000 - 5
1000001 - 9901
1000002 - 166667
1000003 - 1000003
1000004 - 89
1000005 - 409
1000006 - 71429
1000007 - 34483
1000008 - 43
1000009 - 3413
1000010 - 9091
1000011 - 333337
1000012 - 19231
1000013 - 383
1000014 - 166669
1000015 - 200003
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя делить, значит деление надо написать. Обойдёмся только числами без знака, сложением, вычитанием, неравенствами.

Процедура `divmod` делит два числа с остатком. Фактически это двоичный поиск, потребуется логарифм операций сложения и вычитания.

Функция `max_prime_factor` выполняет обычное разложение целого на простые. Само разложение выбрасывается, возвращается только максимальный простой делитель. Переменная `i2` хранит квадрат `i`. Умножение запрещено (мною), поэтому квадрат считаем отдельно через сложения.

Что возвращать для `n = 1` не очень понятно. Задание требует вернуть максимальный простой множитель, а таковых у единицы нет вовсе.

В функции `main` есть деления и умножения, но это тестовый код. Его тоже можно переписать, но, кажется, это немного слишком. :)

Решение требует логарифмической памяти от `n`. Работает за время `sqrt(n)log(n)`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void divmod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t *div, uint64_t *mod) {
    if (a < b) {
        *div = 0;
        *mod = a;
        return;
    }
    divmod(a, b + b, div, mod);
    *div += *div;
    if (*mod >= b) {
        *mod -= b;
        ++*div;
    }
}

uint64_t max_prime_factor(uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t i = 2;
    uint64_t i2 = 4;
    uint64_t max_prime_factor = 0;

    while (i2 <= n) {
        uint64_t div;
        uint64_t mod;
        divmod(n, i, &div, &mod);
        if (mod == 0) {
            max_prime_factor = i;
            do {
                n = div;
                divmod(n, i, &div, &mod);
            } while (mod == 0);
        }
        i2 += i + i + 1;
        ++i;
        if (i > 3) {
            i2 += i + i + 1;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    if (n > max_prime_factor) {
        max_prime_factor = n;
    }
    return max_prime_factor;
}

int main() {
    for (uint64_t m = 1; m <= UINT64_MAX / 10U - 10; m *= 10U) {
        for (uint64_t n = m; n < m + 10; ++n) {
            printf("%" PRIu64 " - %" PRIu64 "\n", n, max_prime_factor(n));
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 temp.c
>
> $ time ./a.out 
> 1 - 1
> 2 - 2
> 3 - 3
> 4 - 2
> 5 - 5
> 6 - 3
> 7 - 7
> 8 - 2
> 9 - 3
> 10 - 5
> 10 - 5
> 11 - 11
> 12 - 3
> 13 - 13
> 14 - 7
> 15 - 5
> 16 - 2
> 17 - 17
> 18 - 3
> 19 - 19
> 100 - 5
> 101 - 101
> 102 - 17
> 103 - 103
> 104 - 13
> 105 - 7
> 106 - 53
> 107 - 107
> 108 - 3
> 109 - 109
> 1000 - 5
> 1001 - 13
> 1002 - 167
> 1003 - 59
> 1004 - 251
> 1005 - 67
> 1006 - 503
> 1007 - 53
> 1008 - 7
> 1009 - 1009
> 10000 - 5
> 10001 - 137
> 10002 - 1667
> 10003 - 1429
> 10004 - 61
> 10005 - 29
> 10006 - 5003
> 10007 - 10007
> 10008 - 139
> 10009 - 10009
> 100000 - 5
> 100001 - 9091
> 100002 - 2381
> 100003 - 100003
> 100004 - 1087
> 100005 - 113
> 100006 - 1613
> 100007 - 1031
> 100008 - 463
> 100009 - 157
> 1000000 - 5
> 1000001 - 9901
> 1000002 - 166667
> 1000003 - 1000003
> 1000004 - 89
> 1000005 - 409
> 1000006 - 71429
> 1000007 - 34483
> 1000008 - 43
> 1000009 - 3413
> 10000000 - 5
> 10000001 - 909091
> 10000002 - 35461
> 10000003 - 769231
> 10000004 - 18797
> 10000005 - 666667
> 10000006 - 563
> 10000007 - 10627
> 10000008 - 138889
> 10000009 - 434783
> 100000000 - 5
> 100000001 - 5882353
> 100000002 - 1187
> 100000003 - 155521
> 100000004 - 5101
> 100000005 - 952381
> 100000006 - 101833
> 100000007 - 100000007
> 100000008 - 154321
> 100000009 - 671141
> 1000000000 - 5
> 1000000001 - 52579
> 1000000002 - 3943
> 1000000003 - 141623
> 1000000004 - 148721
> 1000000005 - 66666667
> 1000000006 - 500000003
> 1000000007 - 1000000007
> 1000000008 - 167
> 1000000009 - 1000000009
> 10000000000 - 5
> 10000000001 - 27961
> 10000000002 - 1666666667
> 10000000003 - 1428571429
> 10000000004 - 2500000001
> 10000000005 - 666666667
> 10000000006 - 33557047
> 10000000007 - 189613
> 10000000008 - 1298027
> 10000000009 - 295081
> 100000000000 - 5
> 100000000001 - 8779
> 100000000002 - 1543067
> 100000000003 - 100000000003
> 100000000004 - 1422637
> 100000000005 - 215659
> 100000000006 - 12667849
> 100000000007 - 283286119
> 100000000008 - 462962963
> 100000000009 - 10477
> 1000000000000 - 5
> 1000000000001 - 99990001
> 1000000000002 - 166666666667
> 1000000000003 - 1152763
> 1000000000004 - 501001
> 1000000000005 - 66666666667
> 1000000000006 - 117674747
> 1000000000007 - 28969553
> 1000000000008 - 8331667
> 1000000000009 - 519217
> 10000000000000 - 5
> 10000000000001 - 1058313049
> 10000000000002 - 328121
> 10000000000003 - 48492137
> 10000000000004 - 357142857143
> 10000000000005 - 6605827
> 10000000000006 - 6326063
> 10000000000007 - 13901
> 10000000000008 - 6038647343
> 10000000000009 - 3049927
> 100000000000000 - 5
> 100000000000001 - 121499449
> 100000000000002 - 746079353
> 100000000000003 - 276964579
> 100000000000004 - 46904315197
> 100000000000005 - 159234401
> 100000000000006 - 65983
> 100000000000007 - 1012201
> 100000000000008 - 258233
> 100000000000009 - 8705453
> 1000000000000000 - 5
> 1000000000000001 - 9091
> 1000000000000002 - 166666666666667
> 1000000000000003 - 67103479
> 1000000000000004 - 385248971
> 1000000000000005 - 50867
> 1000000000000006 - 27031410499
> 1000000000000007 - 360620266859
> 1000000000000008 - 833316667
> 1000000000000009 - 322459
> 10000000000000000 - 5
> 10000000000000001 - 69857
> 10000000000000002 - 1289733131
> 10000000000000003 - 1428571428571429
> 10000000000000004 - 50010001
> 10000000000000005 - 37884167
> 10000000000000006 - 139449433
> 10000000000000007 - 5396507
> 10000000000000008 - 138888888888889
> 10000000000000009 - 4332288241
> 100000000000000000 - 5
> 100000000000000001 - 21993833369
> 100000000000000002 - 594085421
> 100000000000000003 - 100000000000000003
> 100000000000000004 - 1246820607451
> 100000000000000005 - 2929595521
> 100000000000000006 - 3743297
> 100000000000000007 - 592951213
> 100000000000000008 - 22278185023
> 100000000000000009 - 84530853761623
> 1000000000000000000 - 5
> 1000000000000000001 - 999999000001
> 1000000000000000002 - 52445056723
> 1000000000000000003 - 1000000000000000003
> 1000000000000000004 - 562425889
> 1000000000000000005 - 2187161
> 1000000000000000006 - 77724234416291
> 1000000000000000007 - 729644203597
> 1000000000000000008 - 166667
> 1000000000000000009 - 1000000000000000009
>
> real  2m33.545s
> user  2m32.512s
> sys   0m0.020s
> ```